# Problem selecting the value from a JComboBox binded to a list

Tags: java, swing, jpa, netbeans6.7

I have a JComboBox binded to an observable list (result of a jpa query) in a java desktop application. It gets all the values from that list and displays them correctly, but I'm not able to select any particular value from the dropdown: that is, when I click on the widget the list of options gets displayed correctly, when I click on an item the list closes and the first value is shown independently from the selection of that particular item.

However, no exception is thrown.

This problem occurs if I have more than a model associated to the same entitymanager.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger to see what happens when the ComboBoxModel's setSelectedItem method gets called?

Comment: I have no ComboBoxModel associated, it is binded with netbeans bind methods.

Comment: ... and no exception is thrown during the execution, so I have no idea of where to stop methods during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using two separate entitymanagers for each model I have in the frame.